# Google cloud sdk root from PS C:\Users\mausa\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK> to this studentplan@instance-1 ~] $

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sdk

I have installed google SDK on my computer, connected with google cloud account, able to see the project list and other info with "`gcloud init`" command.

No the problem is that the root that I am getting to write all commands here is this - `C:\Users\mausa\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK>` I want to have root something like this `computerplan@instance-1 ~] $`  so that I can use it for that instance.

Please anybody help me in this.